# Failing to update the table based on checked value

Tags: android-studio, checkbox, android-asynctask, sql-update, jtds

I've a `listview` from the database with checkbox. My objectives is to insert the checked `listview` into a table and update another table based on the checked `listview`. Unfortunately, my SQL query did not work in the section.

Here is my code to insert the checked listview into BRTR table and update rows in WORKTR table based on the checked listview:

```
 // Get Item Checked
        Button btnGetItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetItem);
        btnGetItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int count = lisView1.getAdapter().getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)lisView1.getChildAt(i); // Find by under LinearLayout
                    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.ColChk);
                    if(checkbox.isChecked()) {
                        PFNO = checkbox.getTag().toString();

                        try {
                            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                            if (con == null) {
                                z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                            } else {
                                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                                String ReasonAll = "Break-All";
                                String dates = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                                String currentTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                                String query = "insert into BRTR (PF_No,start_break,work_date, reason_break) values('" + PFNO + "','" + currentTime + "','" + dates + "', '" + ReasonAll + "' )";
                                st.executeQuery(query);

                                if (st.executeUpdate(query) == 1) {
                                    String query2 = "Update WORKTR set status ='" + b_status + "' where Start_date='" + dates + "' and Pf_no='" + PFNO + "' and Scan_by='" + PIC + "' and status='" + a_status + "'";
                                    st.executeUpdate(query2);
                                    if(st.executeUpdate(query2)==1){
                                        Toast.makeText(DataModel.this, "Breaktime Recorded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }else{
                                        Toast.makeText(DataModel.this, "Update fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(DataModel.this, "Breaktime fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {

                        }

                        Log.d("Item " + String.valueOf(i), checkbox.getTag().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(DataModel.this, checkbox.getTag().toString() + " Recorded for break", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
//                Toast.makeText(DataModel.this,"Breaktime Recorded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

The application result to not responding when it comes to the second query. Please help me to view and solve this problems.

Comment: I suggest creating a [MRE] as it stands there is a lot of code for someone to look through. Create a minimal example that still shows the same problem and it will be much easier for someone to assist.

Comment: @DaleK how about this time? I already edit the posted code, focusing on the btnGetItem

Comment: Thats certainly more manageable (I don't know the technology myself). However what actually is the issue, I get its not working, but is it throwing an error? What happens when you step through it with a debugger? Does it run the correct code? Investigate and provide as much detail about what is actually happening as possible.

Comment: @DaleK it doesn't show any error but only a query that comes first. let say I put the update query before the insert query, it will only run the update query and ignore other query after that.